# DataView syntax for constructor to get all values which are like a Row

Tags: c#, dataset

How I have to set the RowFilter in a Dataview, that I recive all Values from a Row (in my case iSBN) which are **like** the search string (in my case it's isbn)
I've tryed the following code, but it didn't successed.
I thought it has to be SQL Syntax, but may I'm wrong.

This code works. For what I'm looking forward too.

```
DataView custView = new DataView(_dset.Tables["Book"], "ISBN like '%isbn%'", "ISBN", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows); 

DataView custView = new DataView(_dset.Tables["Book"], "", "ISBN", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

_lBdatenOutput.Items.Clear();
foreach (DataRowView myDRV in custView)
{
    DataRow dr = myDRV.Row;
    if((dr["ISBN"].ToString().IndexOf(isbn) >= 0))
    {
        foreach (DataColumn cl in custView.Table.Columns)
        {
             _lBdatenOutput.Items.Add("Spalten-Name:  " + " \t " + cl.ColumnName + " \t" + dr[cl]);
        }
        _lBdatenOutput.Items.Add(seperator1);
    }
```

And what do i have to put into the constructor of the Dataview, that I can solve it with the following code?

```
DataView custView = new DataView(_dset.Tables["Book"], "ISBN like '%isbn%'", "ISBN", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        DataRowView[] foundRows = custView.FindRows(new object[] { isbn });
        if (foundRows.Length == 0)
        {
            _lBdatenOutput.Items.Clear();
            _lBdatenOutput.Items.Add("No matches found");
        }
        else
        {
            _lBdatenOutput.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRowView myDRV in foundRows)
            {
                DataRow dr = myDRV.Row;
                foreach (DataColumn cl in custView.Table.Columns)
                {
                    _lBdatenOutput.Items.Add("Spalten-Name:  " + " \t " + cl.ColumnName + " \t" + dr[cl]);
                }
            }
        }
```

My Boss sat to the right hand side of me and tryed 1 hour, so you would be great if you find an answer

Thank you for your help

Comment: If i understand your code correctly, you want to find any rows where part of the ISBN is the ISBN? That would simply return all rows because every ISBN is part of itself. The [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) for this redundant filter would be: `custView.RowFilter = "ISBN LIKE '%' + ISBN + '%'"`. If you instead have a variable called `isbn` and you want to find all matching records, following Expression will work: `"ISBN LIKE '%" + isbn + "%'"` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: Thanks, That's it. Why don't you post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your code correctly, you want to find any rows where part of the ISBN is the ISBN? That would simply return all rows because every ISBN is part of itself. The [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) for this senseless filter would be:

```
custView.RowFilter = "ISBN LIKE '%' + ISBN + '%'";
```

If you instead have a variable called `isbn` and you want to find all matching records, following Expression will work:

```
custView.RowFilter = "ISBN LIKE '%" + isbn + "%'";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx